# i want to read the file and write destinations into the destination array and prices into the price array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written a file with 4 holiday destination and there prices , so i want to read the file and write destinations into the destination array and prices into the price array. the text format is like

```
suncity 250
ushakamarue 300
krugerPark 450
Tablemountain 340
```

this is what i have

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

//define a constant for the number of lines to read 
#define NUM_READ_LINES 4
int main()
{

    // array of line numbers each line being less or equal to 100 chars

     char destination[NUM_READ_LINES][100];
     //string price[30];
     int counter = 0;
     //ofstream outfile;
     ofstream outfile("program.txt");
     if(outfile.is_open())
     {
         outfile <<"suncity 250\n ";
         outfile <<" ushakamarue 300\n";
         outfile <<" krugerPark 450\n";
         outfile <<" Tablemountain 340\n";
     }

     else 
       cout <<"Unable to open to file";

     outfile.close();

     //open a file
       ifstream infile;
       infile.open("program.txt");


      if(infile.good())
      {
        //Read throuh file and load into array
    while(!infile.eof() && (counter < NUM_READ_LINES))
    {
        infile.getline(destination[counter], 100);
        counter++;
    }
    //loop hrough the array which we just put together
    for (int i=0; i < counter;i++ )
        {
            cout << destination[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    infile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Currently the program is reading the whole line suncity 250 as destination instead of reading only suncity into destination[1] and 250 into Price[1].

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Currently the program is reading the whole line suncity 250 as destination instead of reading only suncity into destination[1] and 250 into Price[1]. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
     string destination[NUM_READ_LINES];
     string price[NUM_READ_LINES];

     ifstream infile("program.txt");
     for (int ii = 0; ii < NUM_READ_LINES; ++ii) {
         infile >> destination[ii] >> price[ii];
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.